# Calculating sumif between tables in powepivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot, sumifs

So I have one table, 'Positions', containing two columns, CptyExposure (text) and MarketvalueSEK. 
Table two, 'Counterparties', only contains one column with distinct CptyExposure.

Table one contains 190 rows where the cptyexposure category is recurring on many rows.
My goal is to in table two have the summarized market value for every Cpty.

To get the sumif-formula to work within table one I use the following formula:
    =CALCULATE(sum(Positions[MarketvalueSEK]);ALLEXCEPT(Positions;Positions[CptyExposure]))

But how do I do this between Table 'Positions' and table 'Counterparties'?

```
Table1:

CptyExposure |  MarketValueSEK
NORDEA       |  110 000 000
NORDEA       |    3 000 000
NYKREDIT     |   10 000 000
NYKREDIT     |   20 000 000
DANSKE BANK  |   16 930 000
DANSKE BANK  |   27 200 000
DANSKE BANK  |   60 000 000




  Table2:

CptyExposure |  DesiredSumIF-Column
NORDEA       |  113 000 000
NYKREDIT     |   30 000 000
DANSKE BANK  |  104 130 000
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. Found the answer.

```
=CALCULATE(sum(Positions[MarketvalueSEK]);filter(Positions;Positions[CptyExposure]=Counterparties[CptyExposure]))
```